# Discord.py | Adding reactions to message

Tags: python, discord.py

Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    author = message.author
    channel_id = message.channel.id
    if channel_id == suggestions_channel_id:
        await message.add_reaction(":white_check_mark:")
        await message.add_reaction(":x:")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

I am getting error:
`discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji`
Why is this an unknown emoji? It is a public emoji `:white_check_mark:` ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Forgot has to be unicode
Go to any discord channel and do
\:emoji_name:
Will give you the unicode.